# how to call excel macro which contains call of external add-in from C# application?

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I have C# console application which calls excel, opens excel template and runs number of macros. My macro contains calls of functions from external add-in. the application is supposed to run every night, so I'm using scheduled tasks for this purpose. The problem is that when application runs as scheduled task add-in functions are ignored because excel is running in this case as background process. 
Has somebody faced with such kind of problem?

Elena

Answer (score 0):

I use excel from windows service, and I use macros as you.
And all work fine.

So I suggest to run excel not from standart sheduller.
Use external software for it, or implement custom windows service.

Comment: And you also called functions from external excel add-in? My macro executes fine except calls of external add-in functions. And I tried to use Windows service and I had the same issue. So i was thinking that there can be some problem if you are trying to call some functions from add-in in your macro.

Comment: Here is my macro `code` Sub update(thomsonTicker As String) Application.Sheets("Annual").Select Range("K5") = thomsonTicker Sleep (30000) Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorkbook Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name) Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorksheet Sheets("PL") 'Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorksheet Sheets("BS") Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorksheet Sheets("GCM") End Sub `code`

Comment: And these funtions Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorkbook Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name) Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorksheet Sheets("PL") 'Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorksheet Sheets("BS") Application.COMAddIns("ThomsonONE.AddinShim").Object.RefreshWorksheet Sheets("GCM") for some reason are ignored when excel is running as background process